# Can jWebSocketSenchaPlugIn work in sencha architect?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Sencha architect 3.1, extjs 5.0 project, I want to use jWebSocketSenchaPlugIn in it. After finished 3 steps in jwebsocket document [Sencha-Integration](https://jwebsocket.org/documentation/reference-guide/Sencha-Integration) 3, form.submit doesn't send websocket but url. Could someone tell me how to make it work?

Comment: for why exactly you are using `jWebScoket` with extjs ?

Comment: @AbhijitMuke My project is build on extjs 5. Afterwards I need feature of jWebsocket, so I add jWebsocket in.I don't want to rewrite the project.I look the source os jWebsocket.js, it has many document.getElementById('script'), it obviously is not for sencha architect.Do you have a version for sencha architect?

Comment: I will say if you feel uncomfortable and problematic with `jWebsocket` integration with Extjs..I will suggest to use simple HTML 5 web socket which may fulfill every ability of `jWebsocket` without any integration of third party library...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

Comment: My clients varies from i6 to ie9. But I am very appreciating your advise,it encourage me overcome this problem.